# How to setup a load balancer with x app services

Tags: azure

I have two app services (web apps), running the same code, hosted in azure at.
web1.azurewebsites.net and web2.azurewebsites.net (and possibly webN.azurewebsites.net)

I want to have a single web address (for example https://web1.azurewebsites.net or just any web address) and a load balancer that shares the load between them from the incomming requests.

How do I set up this in Azure. I dont understand the terminology and the guides Ive found is old.

Ive managed to create a Load Balancer with a public (dynamic) IP, but I dont know what host name that would answer to, nor how to connected it to my app services)

Could anyone guide me, either just a tutorial (no generic links please), or some step by step instructions how to do it.

Comment: Quick question - why not use a single app service with multiple instances?

Comment: Hmm.. I dont know really, now that you mention it I remember that that is an option (and probably the correct one for the frontends!)... Im trying to setup a Umbraco-Master and some frontends (https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/flexible). I still  *think* I'll need at least one for master and multiple instances for the frontends. I will look into this more closely, thanks.

Comment: Generally, if you just want multiple instances of the exact same app in the same region, I would use multiple instances (scale out your app service plan). If you want these balanced across regions, use a Traffic Manager Profile. When you set that up, it lets you select specific from your app services to use as endpoints. If scaling out doesn't work, I'd recommend looking into that... I would think it would work for apps in the same region even if that isn't the intention.

Comment: You are probably right, scaling out is the correct way to go for the frontends. But it would be nice to have the master (which is slightly differently configured) at same web address, and also it could serve as a frontend as well.

Comment: Jason: Please create an answer so I can set it to "correct" so you can get your credits. I will use your solution and have a different address for my master(CMS Back office). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to load balance multiple instances of the exact same app service, you can just scale out your app service plan to let Azure create the instances and do the load balancing for you.
- If that doesn't work for your situation or you want to load balance across regions, use a Traffic Manager.